# Attribute JsonProperty works incorrect with .NET Core 3.1 when I use underscore symbol

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I have the following JSON for patch request:

```
{
    "idfa": "28A427FE-770B-4FA3-AA8E-123",
    "idfv": "11B3343C-ECBB-4CC8123B5BA-DDD9CA5768FD",
    "app_build_number": 1,
    "app_version": "1.0.0",
    "screen_height": 820,
    "screen_width": 300,
    "locale": "ru",
    "app_id": "com.hello",
    "app_platform": "iOS",
    "manufacturer": "Apple",
    "model": "iPhone10,6",
    "os_version": "12.3.1",
    "sdk_version": "0.3"
}
```

And the following model for mapping:

```
    public class CustomerChangeViewModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("idfa")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required idfa")]
        public string Idfa { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("idfv")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required idfv")]
        public string Idfv { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required app_build_number")]
        [JsonProperty("app_build_number")]
        public string AppBuildNumber { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("app_version")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required app_version")]
        public string AppVersion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("screen_height")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required screen_height")]
        public string ScreenHeight { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("screen_width")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required width")]
        public string ScreenWidth { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("locale")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required locale")]
        public string Locale { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("app_id")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required app_id")]
        public string AppId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("app_platform")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required app_platform")]
        public string AppPlatform { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("manufacturer")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required manufacturer")]
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("model")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required model")]
        public string Model { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("os_version")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required os_version")]
        public string OsVersion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sdk_version")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required sdk_version")]
        public string SdkVersion { get; set; }
    }
```

And controller:

```
[Route("/api/v1.0/startup")]
[HttpPatch]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody] CustomerChangeViewModel viewModel)
{
    ...
}
```

After sending this request I have the following: 
[image]

As you can see not all fields were mapped. I think there is a problem with fields with "_" symbol. Any ideas why it's happening? I use .NET Core 3.1 and Insomnia as HTTP client.

P.S I'm not sure is it necessary here, but my routing settings is:

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
       endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

.NET Core 3.* is using `System.Text.Json` by default and it doesn't work with `JsonPropertyAttribute` class.

You need to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
```

And call `AddNewtonsoftJson` extension method to set ASP.NET Core project to use `Newtonsoft.Json` packages.

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

**Related links**

[Using Newtonsoft.Json In .NET Core 3+ Projects](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/19/using-newtonsoft-json-in-net-core-3-projects/)

Answer (score 32):

Also you can use [`[JsonPropertyName("model")]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=netcore-3.1) attribute instead of `[JsonPropertyAttribute("model")]` if you want to use native `System.Text.Json` for .net core 3.1

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, if already using .NET Core 3.1 one should try to use the "native" `System.Text.Json` instead of installing a third party library

Comment: @FelipeSuárez, unfortunately the issue persists with `System.Text.Json` with the `JsonPropertyName` attribute, so a third-party library may be the best option for now.

Comment: To use the attribute in .Net Core 3.1 you need to add :
`using System.Text.Json.Serialization`