# JsonProperty(Newtonsoft) not working properly/ignore in .NET6.0

Tags: json, json.net, .net-6.0

In **.NET 6.0** application it uses **Newtonsoft** library for JSON serialization. It uses ***JsonProperty*** attribute for alias naming in response. However, it provides actual property name(*FileName* in our example rather it should be *label*) instead of alias name.

Controller:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GetAllFiles(string appId)
    {var files = GetAFiles(appId); return Ok(files);}
```

Model:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "label")]
public string FileName { get; set; }
```

Expected Response:

```
[{"label":"test.pdf"}]
```

Comment: I am sure that `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "label")]` will work with standalone Newtonsoft serialization in .NET 6.  Are you sure you aren't actually using System.Text.Json as is the case in [Attribute JsonProperty works incorrect with .NET Core 3.1 when I use underscore symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59914611)?  Try adding `[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("label")]` to `FileName` to see if the problem resolves itself.  Also, try looking through the answers to [JSON.Net serializer ignoring JsonProperty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8424151/3744182) to see if any apply.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment(added the library in Parent project) partially helps me

Answer (score -1):

Root cause: **JsonProperty** attribute was getting ignored, so it was not applying. To resolve the issue, Newtonsoft library(same version) is added which was referred in other class library(Model).

Secondly, **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson** nuget package is added in main project in Startup.cs with following code snippet:

```
services.AddMvcCore().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

In Model

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "label")]
public string FileName { get; set; }
```